# Django don't want to back to previous setting

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project which has payment page and will be redirect to success page after payment completed. However, if user click the go back button of browser will go back to the payment page and show the error: Order matching query does not exist. Does there has any way to fix this?

views.py for payment process:

```
def payment_process(request):
order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
context ={
    'order':order
}
amount = int(order.get_total() * 100)
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        ......

        # create the Payment
        payment = Payment()
        payment.save()

        # assign the payment to the order
        order_items = order.items.all()
        order_items.update(ordered=True)
        order.ordered = True
        order.payment = payment
        order.save()

        messages.success(request, "Success")
        return redirect('payment_success')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(request, 'Failed')
        return redirect('/')
else:
    return render(request, 'payment.html', context)
```

Comment: Becasue you have set `order.ordered = True` and there will not be any `Order` wrt the user

Comment: any way to make the error page looks better?